# How do I format the value shown in a ColumnField using Sitecore Rocks?

Tags: experience-profile, sitecore-rocks

In `Sitecore Rocks` -- when editing `ColumnField` -- how do I format the text in a field?

Basically, I have data being inserted into the ListControl via a SearchDataSource.   One of the fields is a date field and it is coming through as: 
2016-10-26T03:47:53.259Z

I would like it a little cleaner in `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM` format.

I see a field called `Formatter` but not sure what I should put in there.

Answer (score 5):

The Formatter field is really only for date formatting, which is good since that is what you are looking for.

The options for formatting the dates include the following list. Scroll to the bottom to get the full definition and regex treatment applied:

- mmss
- mss
- hmm
- hm
- ms
- ampm
- ap
- yyyy
- yy
- mm
- m
- dd
- d
- hh
- h
- ss
- s

---

## Background Information

### How is Formatter Handled?

The `Formatter` field coming out of the `ColumnField` item type is used in the `ListControl` class as a Backbone `data-bind` attribute.  You can see it in action below. The key to note is the `formatValue(DataField,formatter)` that is being used.

```cs
public virtual string RenderRow()
{
  Item dataSource = this.GetDataSource();
  if (dataSource == null)
    return string.Empty;
  StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
  HtmlTextWriter output = new HtmlTextWriter((TextWriter) stringWriter);
  foreach (Item child in dataSource.Children)
  {
    string str1 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(child["ContentAlignment"]) ? string.Empty : " sc-text-align-" + ClientHost.Items.GetItem(child["ContentAlignment"]).Name.ToLower();
    output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "ventilate" + str1);
    output.AddAttribute("data-sc-important", "data-sc-important");
    string str2;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(child["Formatter"]) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(child["HTMLTemplate"]))
    {
      string str3 = "typeof $data['" + child["DataField"] + "'] != 'undefined' ? $data['" + child["DataField"] + "'] : ''";
      str2 = string.Format("{0},{1}", (object) ("text: " + str3), (object) ("attr: { title: " + str3 + " }"));
    }
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(child["DataField"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(child["HTMLTemplate"]))
      str2 = "html: formatValue('', '" + child["HTMLTemplate"] + "')";
    else
      str2 = string.Format("{0},{1}", (object) ("text: formatValue('" + child["DataField"] + "', '" + child["Formatter"] + "')"), (object) ("attr: { title:  formatValue('" + child["DataField"] + "', '" + child["Formatter"] + "')}"));
    ListControl.SetWidthStyle(output, child);
    output.AddAttribute("data-bind", str2);
    output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);
    output.RenderEndTag();
  }
  return stringWriter.ToString();
}
```

#### `formatValue(object,format)`

This is a Sitecore `ListControl.js` Javascript method that is getting passed through the `data-bind` attribute listed above and executed on the client side when the List is created and displayed. It appears that `formatValue()` really is only meant to handle date formatting. However, as you look at formatValue() method below, you'll note that the `dateConverter.toStringWithFormat()` is getting called out of the Sitecore minified Backbone javascript.

```js
    // apply formating
    itemModel.viewModel.formatValue = function (name, format) {

      var val = "";

      //  Checking for this[name]() invokes binding, so make sure this[name] is a function
      if (typeof this[name] === 'function' && name != "" && typeof this[name]() != 'undefined') {
        val = this[name]();
      }

      var tempValue = '';
      var additionalValues;
      if (this.$formattedFields) {
        additionalValues = this.$formattedFields();
      }

     if (format && format == "short") {
       if (additionalValues && additionalValues[name]) {
          tempValue = additionalValues[name].shortDateValue;
          if (tempValue) val = tempValue;
        }
      }
      else if (format && format == "long") {
        if (additionalValues && additionalValues[name]) {
          tempValue = additionalValues[name].longDateValue;
          if (tempValue) val = tempValue;
        }
      }
      else if (format) {
        var isHtmlTemplate = val == "" && name == "";
        if (isHtmlTemplate) {
          var viewModel = this;
          var getValue = function (fieldname) {
            if (typeof viewModel[fieldname] != "undefined") {
              return viewModel[fieldname]();
            }
            return undefined;
          };
          tempValue = sc.Helpers.string.formatByTemplate(format, getValue);

        } else if (sc.Helpers.date.isISO(val)) {
          var dateConverter = sc.Converters.get("date");
          tempValue = dateConverter.toStringWithFormat(val, format);
        }
        if (tempValue) val = tempValue;
      }

      return val;
    };
    this.collection.add(itemModel);
  }, this);
```

---

### What can I pass into the Formatter Field?

By looking at the `toStringWithFormat` method, you can pretty easily tell what date formatting options you have.

```js
  toStringWithFormat: function (value, format) {
    if (Utils.date.isISO(value)) {
      try {
        var date = Utils.date.parseISO(value);
        var formats = {
          mmss: {
            expression: "(\\W|^)mm(\\W+s{1,2}\\W|\\W+s{1,2}$)",
            value: Utils.date.ensureTwoDigits(date.getUTCMinutes())
          },
          mss: {
            expression: "(\\W|^)m(\\W+s{1,2}\\W|\\W+s{1,2}$)",
            value: date.getUTCMinutes().toString(),
          },
          hmm: {
            expression: "(\\Wh{1,2}\\W+|^h{1,2}\\W+)mm(\\W|$)",
            value: Utils.date.ensureTwoDigits(date.getUTCMinutes()),
          },
          hm: {
            expression: "(\\Wh{1,2}\\W+|^h{1,2}\\W+)m(\\W|$)",
            value: date.getUTCMinutes().toString(),
          },
          ms: {
            expression: "(\\Wss\\W|^ss\\W)00(\\W|$)",
            value: Utils.date.ensureTwoDigits(date.getUTCMilliseconds()),
          },
          ampm: {
            expression: "(\\W|^)AM/PM(\\W|$)",
            value: ((date.getUTCHours() >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM"),
          },
          ap: {
            expression: "(\\W|^)A/P(\\W|$)",
            value: ((date.getUTCHours() >= 12) ? "P" : "A"),
          },
          yyyy: {
            expression: "(\\W|^)yyyy(\\W|$)",
            value: date.getUTCFullYear().toString(),
          },
          yy: {
            expression: "(\\W|^)yy(\\W|$)",
            value: Utils.date.ensureTwoDigits(date.getUTCFullYear() % 100),
          },
          mm: {
            expression: "(\\W|^)mm(\\W|$)",
            value: Utils.date.ensureTwoDigits(date.getUTCMonth() + 1),
          },
          m: {
            expression: "(\\W|^)m(\\W|$)",
            value: (date.getUTCMonth()+1).toString(),
          },
          dd: {
            expression: "(\\W|^)dd(\\W|$)",
            value: Utils.date.ensureTwoDigits(date.getUTCDate()),
          },
          d: {
            expression: "(\\W|^)d(\\W|$)",
            value: date.getUTCDate().toString(),
          },
          hh: {
            expression: "(\\W|^)hh(\\W|$)",
            value: Utils.date.ensureTwoDigits(date.getUTCHours()),
          },
          h: {
            expression: "(\\W|^)h(\\W|$)",
            value: (date.getUTCHours() > 12) ? (date.getUTCHours() - 12).toString() : ((date.getUTCHours() == 0) ? 12 : date.getUTCHours()).toString(),
          },
          ss: {
            expression: "(\\W|^)ss(\\W|$)",
            value: Utils.date.ensureTwoDigits(date.getUTCSeconds()),
          },
          s: {
            expression: "(\\W|^)s(\\W|$)",
            value: date.getUTCSeconds().toString()
          }
        };
```